# Sending data with h:commandLink while navigating to a page in a new tab

Tags: jsf, primefaces, navigation

I want to send the id of the pressed command link in a p:datatable where i will open a new page in a new tab.
The problem is that the value sent is an empty string.  
 
myPage.xhtml

```
<p:dataTable var="item" value="#{bean.myItems}">
   <p:column>
      <h:commandLink action="#{bean.open(id)}" value="#{item.id}" target="_blank">
         <f:param name="id" value="#{item.id}" />
      </h:commandLink>
   </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Note that with h:link everything is fine and no problem
Bean.java

```
public String open(Item item){
   //some query to find a specific data
   //navigation to different pages according to result of queried data
}
```

NavigatedPageController.java

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
   Map<String,String> params = FacesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
   String id = params.get("id");
   //here id is an empty string instead if being the value passed
}
```

Comment: Your `open` takes an `Item` and you appear to be passing an `int`. Is that intentional?

Comment: no problem with that since the return type of open function is a string and what passed as parameter doesn't necessary what type it is